# Saving data frame to csv with column names as strings in R

Tags: r

Hi I have the following data frame:

```
b = data.frame(c(1,2),c(3,4))
> colnames(b) <- c("100.X0","100.00")
> b
  100.X0 100.00
1      1      3
2      2      4
```

I would like to save this as a csv file with headers as strings. When I use write.csv the result ends up being:

```
100.X0  100
   1     3
   2     4
```

It turns the 100.00 to 100, how do I incorporate this?

Comment: I don't see the problem, I've run your code and saving without problem with `write.csv(x = b, file = "./file.csv", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be the way you read the csv file. Certain programs will guess the type and convert (for eg Excel)

Answer (score 0):

Use `write.xls` from package `dataframes2xls` instead:

```
> library(dataframes2xls)
> write.xls(b, "test.csv")
```

> Result :

[image]